# PCB Battery Grounding

Tags: ground

I'm working on a PCB powered solely by a battery. No charging on the device itself.
I have a question about grounding.

Can I connect -BATT to the global ground plane of the PCB? In schematics for the DW01-G battery protection IC, it has two seperate connections for GND and -BATT(like in the diagram below) I'm wondering, can't I just join these together?

[image]

**TLDR: Can GND and -BATT be connected together? If so, why do diagrams have it seperate.**

Comment: If you connect -BATT to GND, what do you plan to do with the MOSFETs?

Comment: @JackB good point. I guess I gotta keep them seperate then. For other ICs, for example a 3.3V voltage regulator with it's Vin as +BATT, do I connect the ground of the voltage regulator IC to global ground then right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the battery protection IC is to disconnect the battery when it's over-discharged. It does that in your schematic by disconnecting the BATT- terminal from the rest of the circuit using those MOSFETs as a switch.

An alternative way of doing it would be to disconnect the BATT+ terminal from the rest of the circuit. But it is usually easier to disconnect the negative side if you are using MOSFETs, because it needs a N-type MOSFET. High side switching needs a P-type MOSFET, and they are more expensive and/or have less good performance.

When the protection circuit disconnects the battery, it is important that it is disconnected from everything (other than the protection IC itself). Anything still connected could draw current, and damage the battery. So every other part of your circuit should be connected to GND, not to BATT-.

Comment: Ah. So in essence, the MOSFETs are providing the GND to BATT- return path. So if I didn't need the MOSFETs (if I wanted no protection), then I could just short GND and BATT-.

Comment: @AlfroJang80 Correct.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the explanation!!